# Set weather location if cookie exists, if not ask for location and save it in a cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

```
//minimize latest news
window.document.querySelector("#ncWrapper > #nc > #action_ncMinMax").click();

//select location in weather
// $("a:contains('München')").click();

// check if variable is stored in cookie
var loc = $.cookie('loc_cookie');
if ( loc != null) {
    alert('loc existiert');
    var loc_exists = 1;
}
else { var loc_exists = 0; };

// only ask for location if no location is saved yet [functions inside if work]
if ( !loc_exists ) {
    var loc = prompt("Wählen Sie den Ort für den Wetterbericht?");
    alert('Sie haben ' + loc + ' als Ort für den Wetterbericht gewählt.');
};

    $("a:contains('" + loc + "')").click();

// save to cookie
$.cookie('loc_cookie', loc);
alert('loc in Cookie gespeichert');
```

Can anyone help me? the `var loc = $.cookie('loc_cookie');` seems not to work. I just copy/pasted it and hope you know, what I want to make the js do.

1. look for cookie -> get cookie and save if it exists
2. if it doesn't exist, ask for location || if if does do nothing.
3. get location.
4. save location in cookie.

Comment: Can you expand on `seems not to work`. We need details of error messages and incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the "var" keyword within the if/else block. By adding it you create a new local variable.

```
// check if variable is stored in cookie
var loc = $.cookie('loc_cookie');
if ( loc != null) {
    alert('loc existiert');
    var loc_exists = 1;                 <- new instance of loc_exists
}
else { var loc_exists = 0; };           <- new instance of loc_exists
```

Should be

```
// check if variable is stored in cookie
var loc = $.cookie('loc_cookie');
var loc_exists;
if ( loc != null) {
    alert('loc existiert');
    loc_exists = 1;
}
else { loc_exists = 0; };
```

Lastly, it might be clearer to use a boolean:

```
if ( loc != null) {
    alert('loc existiert');
    loc_exists = true;
}
else { loc_exists = false; };
```

Comment: Note: The first declaration is a new instance of `loc`, not `loco_exists`.

Comment: thx. Got it working this way:  
 // check if variable is stored in cookie
 var loc = $.cookies.get('loc_cookie');
 if ( loc != null) {
  alert('loc existiert');
  var loc_exists = 1;
 }
 else { var loc_exists = 0; };
 
 // only ask for location if no location is saved yet [functions inside if work]
 if ( !loc_exists ) {
  var loc = prompt("Wählen Sie den Ort für den Wetterbericht?");
  alert('Sie haben ' + loc + ' als Ort für den Wetterbericht gewählt.');
 };
 
 $("a:contains('" + loc + "')").click();
 
 // save to cookie
 $.cookies.set('loc_cookie', loc);
 alert('loc in Cookie gespeichert');

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include the jQuery Cookie plugin to your page in order to use $.cookie. It's not included by default with jQuery.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Johnny Mopp is right.

Your problem is that you've declared the `loc_exists` inside your `if` statement.

To solve this, move the declaration outside and just set its value inside the statement:

```
var loc = $.cookie('loc_cookie');
var loc_exists = 0;
if ( loc != null) {
    alert('loc existiert');
    loc_exists = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my code. Seems to work just fine. Unfortunately die Website added the feature in the meantime ^_^

```
// check if variable is stored in cookie
var loc = $.cookies.get('loc_cookie');
if ( loc != null) {
    alert('loc existiert');
    var loc_exists = 1;
}
else { var loc_exists = 0; };

// only ask for location if no location is saved yet [functions inside if work]
if ( !loc_exists ) {
    var loc = prompt("Wählen Sie den Ort für den Wetterbericht?");
    alert('Sie haben ' + loc + ' als Ort für den Wetterbericht gewählt.');
};

$("a:contains('" + loc + "')").click();

// save to cookie
$.cookies.set('loc_cookie', loc);
alert('loc in Cookie gespeichert');
```